# how to make a correct closure function in Python?

Tags: python, closures

I want to create a function that returns another function which generates some random numbers based on the parameters of the first function, I did the following code nevertheless I got the message "closure is not defined":

```
def func1(current_price, y, z)
    def closure ()
        future_price = random.gauss(0,1)+Current_price+y+z
        return future_price
    return closure
```

the idea is that each time I call closure() it generates a number based on the formula, the next time I call closure() the result should be based on the previous result, reading the result of future_price as current_ price.

Appreciate any suggestion on how to approach the problem.

Comment: You want to return `closure`, not `closure()`. Using the `()` actually calls the function, but you want to return the function object.

Comment: Please update the question with the full Traceback. You also need to show us code which calls `func1()` and deals with the result.

Comment: Please fix your code since this is not valid/executable Python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after changing `return closure()` to `return closure`, the closure doesn't remember the value of `future_price` between calls, because it's a local variable that gets create anew on each call. You need to *initialize* `future_price` in `func1`, then use that as a non-local variable inside the closure.

```
def func1(current_price, y, z):
    future_price = current_price
    def closure():
        nonlocal future_price
        future_price = random.gauss(0,1) + future_price + y + z
        return future_price
    return closure
```

Once you have defined `func1`, each call will create a new function that has its *own* `future_price` to update.

```
f = func1(10, 1, 2)
g = func1(20, 1, 1)
```

You can see the closure in action by digging into some of the `function` object internals.

```
>>> [x.cell_contents for x in f.__closure__]
[10, 1, 2]
>>> [x.cell_contents for x in g.__closure__]
[20, 1, 1]
>>> f()
14.471922798379957
>>> g()
21.911981360352744
>>> [x.cell_contents for x in f.__closure__]
[14.471922798379957, 1, 2]
>>> [x.cell_contents for x in g.__closure__]
[21.911981360352744, 1, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: I too want to understand this. When func1 is called by some piece of code elsewhere, func1 then sets future_price to one of the parameters it receives. func1 then goes on to define another function within itself named closure. but THAT  'sub' function is never actually called.

Comment: Not *in* `func1`, but whoever calls `func1` gets a function back that can be called. `f = func1(a, b, c)`, then `f()` returns a (usually different, as long as `y` and `z` aren't both 0) future price each time it is called.

Comment: ok. I too want to understand this. When func1 is called by some piece of code elsewhere, func1 then sets future_price to one of the parameters it receives. The last statement in func1 is 'return closure'.  Could I alternatively code this like so: omit the future_price assignment. But then make the definition of closure as 'def closure(any_price)',omit the 'nonlocal' declaration, make the next statement in the closure function as 'future_price = random.gauss(0,1) + any_price + y + z', and make the last statement 'return closure(current_price)'   ??

Comment: I was actually editing my first comment but the edit window timed out. The closure function is ACTUALLY called in the last return statement. It would have been nice if the last statement was 'return closure()' to highlight the fact that the word 'closure' is actually a procedure (like in PL1 - remember that language?)

Comment: No, because then you aren't getting back a function; you are just getting back the result of calling `closure`. The purpose of `func1` is to create a scope which `closure` can refer back to each time `closure` gets called, rather than relying on `closure`'s own local scope alone.

Comment: Functions are first-class objects; `closure` is a name referring to a `function` object;  `closure()` is an expression to be evaluated by *calling* that function.

Comment: that makes sense, but when running I got "NameError: name 'closure' is not defined", do you see any reason for that?

Comment: `closure` is a local variable in the scope of `func1`; if you run `f = func1(...)`, then `f` is the name in the calling scope bound to the function `func1` returns.